# HexBytesをjsonにセットする方法に付いて

Tags: python, ethereum

EthereumのGethから取得したTxNo.をjsonに変換しするとエラーになります

```
_res_list = []
_res = {}
_tx = 〜.transact({'from': 〜})
_res['tx'] = _tx
_res_list.append(_res.copy())
_res = {}
return json.dumps(_res_list)


"errorMessage": "Object of type 'HexBytes' is not JSON serializable"
```

HexBytes型の処理がわかるような情報が見つけられず質問しました

0xで始まっているものをjsonに変換するにはどうすると良いでしょうか

0xを外した文字列として戻すというのでも良いですが、可能であれば0xが付いたままの文字列としてjsonにセットできればと思います

お願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました

Web3.toHexを使えば良いだけでした

すみません